# Join information from table A with the information from another table B multiple times

Tags: sql

So this maybe a simple question but I would like to learn if this can be done in one query.

Table A: contains gene information

```
   gene start end
1     a     5   0
2     b     6   1
3     c     7   2
4     d     8   3
5     e     9   4
6     f    10   5
7     g    11   6
8     h    12   7
9     i    13   8
10    j    14   9
```

Table B: contains calculated gene information.

```
   gene1 gene2        cor
1      d     j -0.7600805
2      c     i  0.4274278
3      e     g -0.9249361
4      a     f  0.8567928
5      b     h -0.3018518
6      d     j -0.3723553
7      c     i  0.1617981
8      e     g  0.8575933
9      a     f  0.8409788
10     b     h  0.1506035
```

The result table I'm trying to get is:

```
      gene1 gene2  cor     start1   end1    start2   end2   
1      d     j -0.7600805  8        3       14       9
2      c     i  0.4274278  7        2       13       8
3      e     g -0.9249361  
4      a     f  0.8567928
5      b     h -0.3018518
6      d     j -0.3723553            etc.
7      c     i  0.1617981
8      e     g  0.8575933
9      a     f  0.8409788
10     b     h  0.1506035
```

The method I can think of is to join table A onto table B twice, firstly by `gene1` and then by `gene2`, which would require for an intermediate table. Is there any simpler ways to achieve this in one step?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please dd the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I'm using Oracle. But I think syntax wise they are very similar to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, two joins will do it

You simply need to do this:

```
SELECT b.Gene1
      ,b.Gene2
      ,b.cor
      ,a1.Start AS Start1
      ,a1.End AS End1
      ,a2.Start AS Start2
      ,a2.End AS End2
FROM TableB b
INNER JOIN TableA a1
  ON a1.Gene = b.Gene1 
INNER JOIN TableA a2
  ON a2.Gene = b.Gene2
```

Depending on your dbms you may need to tweek the syntax a bit